# Saber la string que mas se repite en array

Tags: javascript

Suponiendo que tengo un array:

```
var arr =  ["YB | Yazmn", "PdH | Soul's", "YB | Infx," "PdH | Jvoo!", "YB | FK@2"];
```

En este array son solo strings, y en mi contexto(lo que quiero lograr) lo que está antes del `|` son '*clanes*', en este caso solo hay 2 clanes:

> - YB
> - PdH

Como puedo saber ,con un ***array de length fijo de 10 valores***, cual ***es el clan que más se repite***?

Sin `expresiones regulares`? o son necesarias en este caso ? estoy trabado

Además los clanes son agregados por los mismos jugadores.

```
 var clanes = [];
 var b = document.getElementById('registroClan').value;
    clanes.push(b.toString());

  /*  y se me ocurré recorrerlos y ***si coincide*** algun clan con el array `'arr'` se le suma 1 a la variable que se crearía según el clan ingresado.
    */
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length;i++) {


    /* Un problema más es que deberia crear una variable con el nombre del clan, osea si el jugador ingresa el clan llamado 'YB' además de ingresar al array se crearía una variable para así poderle sumar 1 si es que se repite en un futuro.
    */
    variableClan = 0; // <== Solo ilustrativamente, ya que el usuario crearía la variable al introducir su clan y siempre se le asignaria un valor de 0 al comienzo.

    if(arr[i] == clanes[i]) variableClan += 1;

    }
```

Comment: Es posible que agregues un ejemplo de lo que llevas hecho?

Comment: Listo Ivan Botero

Comment: ¿No seria mejor que manejaras el tema de los clanes y jugadores como objetos con propiedades? Asi tendrias la separacion de forma mas ordenada y no tendrias que hacer un split de un string, sino que acceder a un atributo (`.clan` por ejemplo) para obtener el clan de un objeto de tipo `jugador`.

Answer (score 1):

Basta recorrer el array y contar las referencias

```js
function contar_clanes(arreglo)
{
  var clanes = {}

  clanes.maximo = undefined
  
  for (var entrada of arreglo)
    {
      var clan = entrada.split('|')[0].trim()
      var conteo = clanes[clan]
      
      if(conteo != undefined)
        {
          clanes[clan] = ++conteo
          
          if (clanes.maximo == undefined 
              || conteo < clanes[clanes.maximo])
            {
              clanes.maximo = clan
            }
        }
      else 
        {
          clanes[clan] = 1
        }
    }
    return clanes
}

var arr =  ["YB | Yazmn", "PdH | Soul's", "YB | Infx", "PdH | Jvoo!", "YB | FK@2"];
console.log(contar_clanes(arr))
```

### Pseudocódigo

```
funcion contar_clanes(`arreglo`)
{

establecer `clanes` como un nuevo objeto
establecer `maximo` en `clanes` como `indefinido`

para ( cada `entrada` en `arreglo`)
 {
    extraer `clan` en el string `entrada`

    si (existe `clan` en `clanes`) 
     {
        incrementar el `conteo` de `clan` por 1
        si (`maximo` es indefinido 
            o `conteo` de `clan` es mayor a `conteo` de `maximo`)
          {
            establecer `maximo` como `clan`
          }
     }
    sino 
      {
        establecer `conteo` de `clan` a 1
      }
 }

retornar `clanes`

}
```

Comment: Podrias explicarmelo ? por favor

Comment: ¿Qué parte no entiendes?

Comment: Solo para que quede documentado. No copie tu respuesta, lo juro. Ahora veo tu respuesta y tenemos en esencia el mismo codigo.

Comment: @Einer no te preocupes, mi comentario no lo hice para desmeritar el tuyo, sólo para hace enfásis en que ambos ciclos se podrían acoplar en uno sólo.

Answer (score 1):

Guardando en un diccionario cada clan. Si el clan ya existe en el diccionario entonces le sumamos 1 al valor. Al final buscamos cual fue la llave que tuvo mas conincidencias.

```js
var arr= ["YB | Yazmn", "PdH | Soul's", "YB | Infx", "PdH | Jvoo!", "YB | FK@2"];

var diccionario = {};
for(var i = 0; i <arr.length; i++)
{
    // eliminamos los espacios en blanco y separamos el resultado por el |
    var clan = arr[i].replace(" ", "").split("|"); 
    
  // verificamos que el clan exista en el diccionario
   if(diccionario[clan[0]] != undefined){
    // como existe, aumentamos el contador del clan en 1
     diccionario[clan[0]] = diccionario[clan[0]] + 1;
   }
  else{
    // como no existe entonces agregamos el clan al diccionario con un valor inicial a 1
    diccionario[clan[0]] = 1;
  }
}


var valorMasAlto = {conincidencias: 0};

// Recoremos cada elemento del diccionario
for(var property in diccionario)
  {
     
    if(valorMasAlto.conincidencias < diccionario[property])
    {
        valorMasAlto.key = property;
        valorMasAlto.conincidencias = diccionario[property];
    }
  }

console.log(valorMasAlto);
```

Comment: Me temo que dos ciclos no son la opción más eficiente, ya que fácilmente el segundo ciclo se puede evitar. Si el arreglo tiene *n* elementos entonces tu solución requeriría de *2n* iteraciones facilmente reducibles a *n* (la mitad), acoplando tanto el conteo de clanes como la detección del máximo. Es cierto que con o sin acoplación la complejidad final es  *Omega(n)*, así que la penalización es un factor de *2*, despreciables en los computadores de hoy en día. No obstante sí refleja una pobre estrategia empleada y una observación digna de nombrar.

Comment: ¿Como lo reducirias a 1 iteracion? Siento curiosidad.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui tengo un ejemplo de los transportes, podemos contar los elementos repetidos en el array con este codigo.

```
var arraytransporte = ['carro','avion','avion'];
    var contador = 0;
    var repetidos = [];
    var total_numeros = arraytransporte.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < total_transporte; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < total_transporte; j++) {
    if (parseInt(arraytransporte[i]) == parseInt(arraytransporte[j])) {
                contador++;
            }
        }

 if (contador > 1 && repetidos.indexOf(parseInt(arraytransporte[i])) === -1) {
            repetidos.push(parseInt(arraytransporte[i]));
            result.innerHTML += ("<p>El transporte " + arraytransporte[i] + " se repite " + contador + " veces </p>");
        }
        contador = 0;
    }

    // array con los transportes repetidos
    console.log(repetidos);
}
```

Comment: Esto no parece responder al problema específico expuesto en la pregunta.